# mod_rewrite condition for existing folder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set-up an *.htaccess* file that will pass every request URL as `GET` into a file called `index.php`. The only exception is, when the request URL points to a directory *res*.

Examples:

```
/wiki/cool-stuff          => index.php?uri=/wiki/cool-stuff
/wiki/cool-stuff?news=on  => index.php?uri=/wiki/cool-stuff&news=on
/res/cool-photo.jpg       => res/cool-photo.jpg
```

Two problems:

1. The GET variable passed to `/wiki/cool-stuff` in the second example is not passed to *index.php*
2. Accessing `/res` (not `/res/`!!) suddenly shows me `/res/?uri=res` **in my browser** and *index.php* with `uri=res/`. Accessing `/res/` instead, shows me *index.php* with `uri=res/` and the URL in the browser stays (which is okay).

The *.htaccess*:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase   /subthing/

RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    !/res/(.+)$
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    !index.php
RewriteRule   (.*)              index.php?uri=$1
```

How can I achieve the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try using the *Query-String-Append* flag, `QSA`
2. Make the trailing slash optional - in Regex, this is achieved by adding `?`.

New `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase   /subthing/

RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    !/res(/.*)?$
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    !index.php
RewriteRule   (.*)              index.php?uri=$1 [QSA]
```

Note that I have tweaked the Regex on the `/res` folder to cause `/resabc` to be redirected (if the slash was the only optional piece, anything beginning with `res` would match.

[Apache Mod_Rewrite Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tipp with `[QSA]`. That works fine. It seems to be because of firefox that `/res` turns into `/res/?uri=res` in the URL bar. It does not appear in firefox. I want `/res/` (without any trailing stuff) to also be redirected to `index.php`, can you tell me how to achive this?

Comment: @NiklasR This will redirect /res/ if I'm not mistaken. Firefox caches known redirects, which can get messy. Clear browsing history, then please let me know if there's still an issue.